# error creating SQLite DB

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite, insert

I am receiving an error when I am trying to insert data into a SQL DB. The error suggest that my uName column does not exist when its trying to insert data into that column. From my observation this column should be created. I may be missing something.  another eye on this may be helpful.

LogCat:

01-23 20:20:15.532: E/Database(2322): Error inserting uName=xxxx wUrl=xxxxxxxx sName=xxxx pWord=xxxx

01-23 20:20:15.532: E/Database(2322): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table infoTable has no column named uName: , while compiling: INSERT INTO infoTable(uName, wUrl, sName, pWord) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?);

DB Creation:

```
        String sqlDataStore = "create table if not exists " +
        TABLE_NAME_INFOTABLE + " ("+ BaseColumns._ID + " integer primary key autoincrement,"

                    + COLUMN_NAME_SITE + "text not null,"
                    + COLUMN_NAME_ADDRESS + "text not null,"
                    + COLUMN_NAME_USERNAME + "text not null,"
                    + COLUMN_NAME_PASSWORD + "text not null)";

        db.execSQL(sqlDataStore);
```

Here is my class:

public class dataStore extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
//Table attributes
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "SiteLogindb";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String TABLE_NAME_INFOTABLE = "infoTable";

// Data attributes
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_SITE = "sName";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ADDRESS = "wUrl";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_USERNAME = "uName";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_PASSWORD = "pWord";


public dataStore(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
```

Comment: try to uninstall your app completely and install again. If you were developing the app and were changing the DB schema then probably you have a DB with old schema which (again, perhaps) doesn't have uName in it. Since the code creates a table only if it doesn't exist yet, then your old table is preserved over the new one. 
This is only my guess.

Comment: Thanks for the reply How would I accomplish the uninstall from the emulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue was resolved by deleting database from emulator.

Go to DDMS then go to file explorer then open data-->--->data--> then your package ---> then database and here you have your database and you can delete it by clicking minus "-" sign from top right.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the DB_Version to 2:

```
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
```

Comment: changed version to 2 but received same error when running the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

put semicolon in the end of your table definition  like here it solves your probelm

```
TABLE_NAME_INFOTABLE + " ("+ BaseColumns._ID + " integer primary key autoincrement,"

                        + COLUMN_NAME_SITE + "text not null,"
                        + COLUMN_NAME_ADDRESS + "text not null,"
                        + COLUMN_NAME_USERNAME + "text not null,"
                        + COLUMN_NAME_PASSWORD + "text not null);";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing space here after double quotes before text `" text.....`

```
+ COLUMN_NAME_SITE + " text not null,"
+ COLUMN_NAME_ADDRESS + " text not null,"
+ COLUMN_NAME_USERNAME + " text not null,"
+ COLUMN_NAME_PASSWORD + " text not null)";
```

hope it helps

Comment: I added the semicolon and the spacing as instructed and received the same error in LogCat

Comment: drop the database from the emulator using adb shell and re-create it or check the db for yourself using sqlite3 command-line command

Answer (score 0):

See below:

```
        String sqlDataStore = "create table if not exists " +
        TABLE_NAME_INFOTABLE + " ("+ BaseColumns._ID + " integer primary key autoincrement,"

                    + COLUMN_NAME_SITE + " text not null,"
                    + COLUMN_NAME_ADDRESS + " text not null,"
                    + COLUMN_NAME_USERNAME + " text not null,"
                    + COLUMN_NAME_PASSWORD + " text not null);";

        db.execSQL(sqlDataStore);
```